# body 100% height moves on certain actions

Tags: html, css, jquery-select2, alertify

I've got a webpage with a body height of 100%. I'm using the alertify plugin which is for nice dialogs. When I click a button in that dialog the whole page moves about -70px to the top. I've got the same issue when I click an select menu which uses Select2 plugin.

When I remove the 100% height I don't have the problem but I need that height.

Is anyone familiar with this problem or have an idea how to solve it?

Comment: set `body{ overflow:hidden }` may be useful .

Comment: thnx but unfortunately it doesnt work

Comment: Give us an snapshot of your problem + your plugin download or demo link to help

Answer (score 0):

just set the following properties

```
body{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
```

Comment: Oops.Sorry, intended to write margin.

Comment: just see the box model of your page, there you can see the exact reason that which property is going out of the page

Comment: margin is also 0px; but it still happened